# Trying to use a shape button to toggle in VBA to hide or expose a comment

Tags: excel, vba

However, I don't want to use the ActiveXcontrol button.

```
Sub togglingashape()
' I recorded a macro to give me the target shape
' Active.Shapes.Range(Array("Flowchart: Alternate Process 1"))
' to use in condition below :

If Active.Shapes.Range(Array("Flowchart: Alternate Process 1")).Value = True Then

    Range("D3").Comment.Visible = True

Else
    Range("D3").Comment.Visible = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: i'm not on my computer so this is a rough alternative : delete all your sub. Range("d3").shapes.comment.visible=not range("d3").shapes.comment.visible.    .but could be shaperange instead shapes. Sorry for my bad formating, the phone writing is very difficult.

Comment: Nana, please practice using the code formatting controls here, so that your code appears in block formatting, as per my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, call this routine from the click event of the image:

```
Sub CommentOnOff()

Dim cmt As Comment

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Comments.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "There are no comments added to this sheet.", vbOKOnly, "No comments 
on this sheet"
Exit Sub
End If

If Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly Then
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
cmt.Shape.Top = cmt.Parent.Top + 5
cmt.Shape.Left = _
cmt.Parent.Offset(0, 1).Left + 5
Next

Else
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
cmt.Shape.Top = cmt.Parent.Top + 5
cmt.Shape.Left = _
cmt.Parent.Offset(0, 1).Left + 5
Next
End If

Set cmt = Nothing
End Sub
```